# getting nullpointer exception when using camera intent in android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult

I have made a simple android app,In that I want to capture a pic and want to set it into an imageview but it gives me null pointer exception inside onActivityResult ,My logcattrace and code is as below:
**code**

```
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))

                {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");

                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

                }
...
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                Log.i("Your version Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19","if condition");//<19
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                bitmap_selected_image2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                v_iv_photo_main.setImageBitmap(bitmap_selected_image2);
                // finish();
               //  startActivity(new Intent(SelectPhotoCountryActivity.this,SetPhotoFrameActivity.class));

            }
```

**logcat**

```
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.footballapp/com.example.footballapp.SelectPhotoCountryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3518)
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3561)
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:168)
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1377)
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    at com.example.footballapp.SelectPhotoCountryActivity.onActivityResult(SelectPhotoCountryActivity.java:281)
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5563)
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3514)
06-16 14:34:15.564: E/AndroidRuntime(31301):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Where did you initialize your v_iv_photo_main?

Comment: @Zoran-inside oncreate method